# GCP OpenVPN with Win10 OpenVPN Client

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, vpn, openvpn

I'm really bad with networking things, but i tried today to set-up an OpenVPN server using GCP Marketplace following this tutorial:
https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/google-cloud-platform-byol-instance-quick-launch-guide/

When trying to connect using OpenVPN Client on Windows 10, the connection seems ok but no traffic is redirected trough the VPN.

**What i try to acheive is to route all the traffic from my Windows 10 computer trough the OpenVPN Server.**

I think it's just about a settings on the server/client but i can't seem to understand while searching for a solution.

Thanks for the help!
Jimmy

Comment: Edit your question with details. What traffic are you expecting to be routed to GCP? Normally the only traffic that will be routed is traffic for a specific network/subnet. If you are using public IP addresses, those will continue to be routed over the public Internet. You can reconfigure routing to meet your requirements.

Comment: @JohnHanley I edited the question, i'm trying to route all the trafic from my Windows 10 computer via the OpenVPN GCP server.

Comment: I am not sure of this so I will post a comment instead of an answer. You can route all traffic from your Windows 10 desktop to GCP via OpenVPN. However, Google VPCs are not transitive which means the traffic might die at the OpenVPN server for traffic that is destined outside the VPC. I am not sure how (if) the OpenVPN server handles traffic forwarding outside the VPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself.

It was just a configuration to do in the OpenVPN web admin interface to ask the server to re-route all traffic.

I had another issue with DNS, so i did setup DNS manually in the admin interface.

Cheers.
Jimmy